# java.io.FileNotFoundException from Intent.data.toString()

Tags: java, android

Keeping it simple, i have the following code after the user select a song

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    Uri songUri = data.getData();
    File f = new File(songUri.toString());
    try{
        FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);}
    catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Which throws the following error:

> ```
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/49ED-1907/music/etc/Hometown%20TWOP.mp3: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
> ```

Do i need to request permissions? if so, how?

Or what do I need to read the file properly?

Comment: Is the path as Uri of the song

Comment: I do not know what you are using with `startActivityForResult()` that is giving you that particular `Uri`. You should not have any rights to access that file's content, on Android 4.4+, as it is on removable storage.

Comment: I have it as PICK_IMAGE=1; Intent intent = new Intent(); intent.setType("*/*"); intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT); startActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent,"Select file"), PICK_IMAGE); i tried to reuse with modifications a image choser, but I failed so badly

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("/");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.CreateChooser(intent,"Select file"), PICK_IMAGE);
```

First, `"/"` is not a valid MIME type. Please use a valid MIME type, or a wildcard (e.g., `"*/*"`).

Second, `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` will rarely return a `Uri` with a `file` scheme, particularly on Android 5.0+ devices. After all, the user does not have to choose a piece of content that is represented by a file.

To handle that, replace:

```
Uri songUri = data.getData();
File f = new File(songUri.toString());
try{
    FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream(f);}
catch(FileNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();}
```

with:

```
Uri songUri = data.getData();
InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(songUri);
```

Now, you handle both `file` and `content` `Uri` values.